# Laravel and AWS Elastic Beanstalk website not working?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an EC2 development instance with Laravel 5.4 which works absolutely fine, from that I wanted to deploy Elastic Beanstalk app.

I have followed this guide:

https://deliciousbrains.com/scaling-laravel-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-part-3-setting-elastic-beanstalk

Everything seems to be correct the Elastic Beanstalk has been deployed successfully however when I try to go to the url it gives me: http://liveandnow.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

I get:

403 forbidden error with message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

According to the guide once the app has been deployed I should be allowed to see my app under this url but I can't.

Anyone knows why is this happening?

//edit

1 thing to note is that EC2 instances created from Elastic Beanstalk do not have a public ip address however VPC is configured with NAT gateway which has an elastic IP

//edit

Error log in elasticbean

---

/var/log/httpd/error_log

```
 [Sat Aug 19 09:03:48.595736 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 2997] [client 10.0.2.115:11488] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sat Aug 19 09:04:00.251525 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 2971] [client 10.0.0.33:39820] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sat Aug 19 09:04:03.613215 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 3008] [client 10.0.2.115:11492] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
  10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:08:56:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
   10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:00:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:01:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:02:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:03:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.33 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:04:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.2.115 (-) - - [19/Aug/2017:09:04:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
  league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
  league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
  league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
  laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.5).)
  laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
  laravel/framework suggests installing nexmo/client (Required to use the Nexmo transport (~1.0).)
  laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
  laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~2.0).)
  laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to psr7 bridging features (0.2.*).)
  aws/aws-sdk-php suggests installing aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator (To validate incoming SNS notifications)
  aws/aws-sdk-php suggests installing doctrine/cache (To use the DoctrineCacheAdapter)
  intervention/image suggests installing intervention/imagecache (Caching extension for the Intervention Image library)
  psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
  psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
  predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and deserialization of the Redis protocol)
  sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
  phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.5.1)
  phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
  phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
  Writing lock file
  Generating optimized autoload files
  > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
  > php artisan optimize
  Generating optimized class loader
  The compiled services file has been removed.
[2017-08-19T08:53:37.696Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.185Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_logs_dir
  + EB_APP_LOGS_DIR=/var/app/support/logs
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/httpd
  + '[' -f app/SymfonyRequirements.php ']'
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.185Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.185Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.456Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.456Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.472Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.472Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /var/app/ondeck.
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 0 completed
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_flip.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.701Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_flip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/app/current
  + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
  + mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
  + mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
  + nohup rm -rf /var/app/current.old
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.701Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/99_reload_app_server.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.779Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/99_reload_app_server.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Equivalent Upstart operations: start httpd, stop httpd, restart httpd, status httpd
  Gracefully restarting httpd
  [OK]
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.779Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.780Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.780Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + chmod 0755 /var/run/httpd
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy httpd
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AppDeployStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application version switch - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 1 completed
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.111Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.112Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.112Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.112Z] INFO  [2425]  - [Application update app-9fe7-170819_085316@6] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.468Z] INFO  [3375]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.404Z] INFO  [1450]  : Executing command CMD-AppDeploy activities...
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.404Z] DEBUG [1450]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.404Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.522Z] DEBUG [1450]  : Running stages of Command CMD-AppDeploy from stage 0 to stage 1...
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.522Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.522Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running leader election...
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.770Z] INFO  [1450]  : Instance is Leader.
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.771Z] DEBUG [1450]  : Loaded 6 actions for stage 0.
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.771Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 1 of 6 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
[2017-08-19T08:41:13.773Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 2 of 6 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
[2017-08-19T08:41:14.397Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 3 of 6 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
[2017-08-19T08:41:14.674Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 4 of 6 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
[2017-08-19T08:41:34.264Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 5 of 6 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
[2017-08-19T08:41:34.776Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 6 of 6 actions: InfraCleanEbextension...
[2017-08-19T08:41:34.801Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:41:34.802Z] DEBUG [1450]  : Loaded 2 actions for stage 1.
[2017-08-19T08:41:34.802Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 1 of 2 actions: AppDeployEnactHook...
[2017-08-19T08:41:35.075Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running 2 of 2 actions: AppDeployPostHook...
[2017-08-19T08:41:35.285Z] INFO  [1450]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:41:35.374Z] INFO  [1450]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded!
[2017-08-19T08:41:35.374Z] INFO  [1450]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.612Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.612Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-06b93f5de9290cc97)..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] INFO  [2425]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-06b93f5de9290cc97)..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] INFO  [2425]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] INFO  [2425]  : Received command CMD-AppDeploy: {"execution_data":"{\"leader_election\":\"true\"}","instance_ids":["i-06b93f5de9290cc97"],"data":"manifest_1503132800262","command_name":"CMD-AppDeploy","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"d7d5c0a7-84bb-11e7-bba3-1b01bf08a2e3"}
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] INFO  [2425]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.614Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.616Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.616Z] INFO  [2425]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.618Z] INFO  [2425]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.618Z] INFO  [2425]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.618Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Refreshing metadata...
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.881Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.881Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.882Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.882Z] INFO  [2425]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.884Z] INFO  [2425]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.884Z] INFO  [2425]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.884Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::CloudFormation::Init||Infra-WriteApplication2||files..
[2017-08-19T08:53:22.885Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||ManifestFileS3Key..
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.052Z] INFO  [2425]  : Loading manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-2-395260458639' using computed S3 key 'resources/environments/e-mefmdqhgdn/_runtime/versions/manifest_1503132800262'.
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.208Z] INFO  [2425]  : Updated manifest cache: deployment ID 6 and serial 6.
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.208Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-AppDeploy.
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.209Z] INFO  [2425]  : Executing Application update
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.209Z] INFO  [2425]  : Executing command: CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.209Z] INFO  [2425]  : Executing command CMD-AppDeploy activities...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.209Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.209Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.345Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Running stages of Command CMD-AppDeploy from stage 0 to stage 1...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.345Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.345Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running leader election...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.609Z] INFO  [2425]  : Instance is Leader.
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.609Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Loaded 6 actions for stage 0.
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.609Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 1 of 6 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
[2017-08-19T08:53:23.613Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 2 of 6 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
[2017-08-19T08:53:24.046Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 3 of 6 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
[2017-08-19T08:53:24.330Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 4 of 6 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.185Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 5 of 6 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.472Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 6 of 6 actions: InfraCleanEbextension...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] DEBUG [2425]  : Loaded 2 actions for stage 1.
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.497Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 1 of 2 actions: AppDeployEnactHook...
[2017-08-19T08:53:38.779Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running 2 of 2 actions: AppDeployPostHook...
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.020Z] INFO  [2425]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.112Z] INFO  [2425]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded!
[2017-08-19T08:53:39.112Z] INFO  [2425]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.462Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.462Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-06b93f5de9290cc97)..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] INFO  [3375]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-06b93f5de9290cc97)..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] INFO  [3375]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] INFO  [3375]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAIA2VQ62PMCRDFV6A\",\"signature\":\"MCEmNlP\\\/xBc1GizP6ZgnkiD4RY0=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-06b93f5de9290cc97"],"data":"5c412da4-84bd-11e7-8e21-1dd123c4f782","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"5c412da4-84bd-11e7-8e21-1dd123c4f782"}
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] INFO  [3375]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.464Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.465Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.465Z] INFO  [3375]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] DEBUG [3375]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-08-19T09:04:10.467Z] INFO  [3375]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Comment: What is the error in the log file?

Comment: this is the thing where is the log file? I can't get on the ec2 instance as I don't have public dns or public ip for some reason, nwm found it I will put it all as I don't know what is going on

Comment: Not the apache log, show us the Laravel log. It'll be present in the web application's home folder at `storage/logs/laravel*.log`.

Comment: Okay I went to elasticbean settings and I've noticed that document root is empty so I changed it to the right one throught the website and now I have 502 because server is offline, I don't know how to get to elasticbean directly so I view the log

Answer (score 1):

If you sent your project folder zipper, maybe, on configuration you must use `/yourProjectFolderName/public` instead of `/public`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but maybe people would find it helpful in the future. When you deploy your Laravel app to Elastic Beanstalk you must configure this latter to set the root to `/public` since the index.php in Laravel resides in the `public` folder and not the project root. In your case, if you access your website and add `/public` after the URL, it will work.

Simply go to your EB environment and click `Configuration`, then go to `Security` and in the app root field, put `/public`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amine said, you'll need to set the webroot to /public.

If you don't wish to do it via the console and instead in code, create a file:

`.ebextensions/01-settings.config`

With the following content:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /public
```